# Can I add a line break in my Twitter bio?

Tags: twitter, formatting

My Twitter [bio](https://twitter.com/CmisSync1) looks bad because the line is split at unfortunate places.

Can I force a line break at a particular place?

<sub>The form at https://twitter.com/settings/profile inserts carriage returns when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and even saves them, but it does not seem to display them.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution:** Put an equal number of [**non-breaking spaces**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) around your first line.

**What to type:**
[image]

**Demo:** [@maxMRE](http://twitter.com/maxMRE)

**How to type a non-breaking space:**

- **Ubuntu:** Shift+AltGr+[space] on a french (variant) keymap.
- **Anything else:** Your mileage may vary, you have plenty of answers a few keystrokes away.

Copy-pasting non breaking spaces directly in the twitter textarea did not work, I had to type them directly. I wish the web didn't make it so hard to get nice typography.

Comment: That eats up some precious characters, but the best solution so far!

Comment: For windows, hold `Alt` and press `0160`, release `Alt`, and repeat. Works for me - https://twitter.com/imdsm

Answer (score 8):

I fetched my twitter profile with the Twitter API. Here is how it looks -

```
... "screen_name":"iAmBibhas","location":"Bangalore, India","description":"Hungry and lazy developer.\r\nCurrently building @lxidd. ","url":"http:\/\/bibhas.in", ...
```

As you can see, there is `\r\n` just before `Currently building @lxidd`. That means the line breaks are being saved in Twitter database. They just remove it while showing on the profile page. Any 3rd party app that fetches this information, will have that line break, unless removed explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

Use `&emsp;` to pad out your bio to force it to a new line. It takes up more space than `&nbsp;` so if you need a lot of space you can use it instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just spent about 15 minutes trying every method listed.  Finally got it to work by using nbsp;.  Example below:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;.Thinker. Planner. Organizer. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CEO @weBounty
```

You're limited to how many you can use due to character limit.

Answer (score 1):

I used fillers (- - - hyphens and spaces - - -)

it seemed to work for me well enough as a hack https://twitter.com/tomstafford

Comment: +1 Interesting approach! Does it do the trick on all browsers, including mobile browsers? I guess it does not play that well with third-party Twitter clients?

Answer (score 0):

In the edit box press (do not release <kbd>Alt</kbd> button while you are pressing numbers):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + (in numpad) 255

after you release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button, it will create a white space. Copy that and use as much you need.

[Source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lx_4PlIo5pc).

Comment: I am on Linux and ALT+255 does something else... could you please copy-paste that character to your answer, so that anyone can easily copy-paste it? Do you know how this character is called? Thanks!